# mysql node: connection undefined error

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm running into a strange error,which probably results from my inadequate understanding of mysql/node:

Currently, I'm running a script that attempts to make 500,000 calls (in total) to a function that queries a mysql database.
The error I'm encountering appears after a few thousand iterations, when all of a sudden "connection", i.e., the object created by pool.getConnection
is suddenly undefined and my code crashes.

I thought that perhaps this has to do with the fact that I have too many connections open, but since the code which 
runs into this error occurs as part of the callback function AFTER getting a connection, I'm confused.
If anyone could take a look at my code (the one that gets run 500,000 times) and give me some advice, I'd really appreciate it!
As a final note, I noticed that when I call connection.destroy() instead of connection.release(), I do not get any error.
However, when I do that, the database does not get written to!

Thanks again...

```
function addOrUpdate(food, info){
    try{
    pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
        if (typeof(food)!="string" || typeof(info)!="object"){
            connection.release();
            return;}
        if(info['length']==0){
            connection.release();   
            return;
        }
        var f=connection.escape(food);
        connection.query("SELECT * FROM nut where name like "+f, function (err,results){
            if (err) throw err;
            if (results.length==0){
                console.log("INSERT INTO nut (name) values ("+f+")");
                connection.query("INSERT INTO nut (name) values ("+f+")");
                for(var key in info){
                    var v=connection.escape(info[key]);
                    console.log("UPDATE nut SET "+key+"="+v+" where name ="+f);
                    connection.query("UPDATE nut SET "+key+"="+v+" where name ="+f);
                }
            }
            connection.release();
        });
    });
    }
    catch(e){
        console.log('alternative error');
        connection.release();
}}
```

Comment: what is 'err' value when connection is undefined in `getConnection`? The callback is called after successful or unsuccessful getting a connection. Also, what are your pool options? (pool size, max queue size etc)

Comment: The first method I call on "connection" is connection.escape(food). So the first error is "TypeError: Cannot call method 'escape' of undefined". Is there a way to check if a connection was unsuccessful? I defined my pool with the default settings, I haven't specified size or max queue size. Thank you for the help! As a side note, I tried checking to see if typeof(connection) is undefined and returning when it is - this works, but from then on all "connection"s are also undefined. I was thinking perhaps I have too many connections open? Though I've been careful to always close them...

Comment: Yes, check error argument of your `getConnection` function callback parameter. Release does not close connection but returns it to pool

Comment: Another thing to do is run `show processlist;` in mysql to see how many active connections you have as it runs. Even though you will need to handle a failed connection anyway, you may still want to increase mysql's max connections (and max errors too). In mysql, use `Set Global max_connections=250;` and `Set Global max_connect_errors=200;`

Comment: I ran `show processlist;` and it seems like the amount of connections increases and increases until it hits 250 (I changed it as you recommended), and then I run into an error. Is there a way to force node to wait for an open connection? I can think of a hacky way, using a sleep function that I could write, however, surely there is a more elegant way?

Comment: (see comment above as well) If release does not close an open connection, then what is going on? What does connection.destroy() do? After the error is reached, when I run `show processlist;` it says that all my connections are in "sleep"